# Not Enough Space in /ROOT Partition

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, root

I need help locating the specific file that has filled my root partition and the cause of inconsistent file storage usage.
this is the output of my `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           767M  1.9M  765M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda8       7.5G  3.9M  7.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /.snapshots
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /srv
/dev/sda6        16G  1.7G   13G  12% /var
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /root
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /usr/local
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /var/lib/accountsservice
/dev/sda5        85G   81G  7.5M 100% /var/lib/gdm3
/dev/sda1       502M  320K  502M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda9       184G  179G  2.5G  99% /home
tmpfs           767M  152K  767M   1% /run/user/130
tmpfs           767M  176K  767M   1% /run/user/1000
```

how is it possible to have a / partition size of 85GB and 81GB in use and an available size is 7.5M.?.Still I can't operate my Linux normally due to this condition.

Comment: "how is it possible to have a / partition size of 85GB and 81GB in use and an available size is 7.5M" => https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352080/70524, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/70524

Comment: Your problem is not the difference between the partition size and the available space, your problem is the filling-up to 100% of the root partition. The question is closed because the first already has an answer. A bit harsh, I think. Ask the question again, but now "how do I find what is filling-up my root partition"

Comment: apologies, for the tone used. I would like to ask if this current problem exist also on btrfs file system because it's the filesystem I use on my laptop. can I re-edit the question.

Comment: and I can say I have noticed my free space at least reaching 3GB, so am guessing it might not be a problem of reserved space

Comment: If there is a single large file using too much space, you can find it with `find / -xdev -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n`